# How can I to fliter CSV file By author and by title?

Tags: php, csv

How can I filter the file "By author" and "By name"? It turned out only to read the file itself. I do not know what to do next.

```
if (isset($_POST['filter'])) {
    $row = 1;
    if (($handle = fopen("books.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
            $num = count($data);
            $row++;
            for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
                echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
            }
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }
}
```

[image: picture]

Comment: You probably want to use a DB. What does your CSV look like?

Comment: You can use mapping feature as described in this link [csv mapping 1](http://i1t2b3.com/2009/01/14/quick-csv-import-with-mapping/) . Or like this [csv mapping 2](http://www.jayjohnston.com/php/csv-import--use-header-row-to-make-a-field-map).